# Create User using JSON API

Tags: plugin-json-api

I am using JSON API for get the post list from my App.

I need to create user(Register new user) from App. May I know how to add new function to Wordpress JSON-API?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Why you will change, enhance the WP JSON API. You can use the default functions to create a user and use your json content data to use the values on the functions.

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with that plugin and a new [JSON Rest API](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/06/17/json-rest-api/) will maybe be included in core with one of the future versions. So far it's as well available as plugin.

To make it short: There currently seems to only be three kinds of Controllers in that plugin

1. Core
2. Posts
3. Respond

But there's a section on the ***main*** plugin page that explains [how to extend the plugin and how to develop JSON API Controllers](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#5.2.-Developing-JSON-API-controllers). So It's actually just a slightly modified ***copypaste from*** what you could have read in the very excellent and ***detailed plugin page*** !

```
class JSON_API_Hello_Controller
{
    public function hello_world()
    {
        return array(
            "message" => "Hello, world"
        );
    }
}
```

> Your controller is now available as `hello`, and exposes one `hello_world` method.
>
> Next, activate your controller from the WordPress admin interface, available from the menu under Settings > JSON API. You can either click on the link to your `hello_world` method from the admin interface or enter it manually. It should have the form: `http://www.example.org/api/hello/hello_world/?dev=1` or `http://www.example.org/?json=hello.hello_world&dev=1` (note the use of the `dev` argument to enable human-readable output). You should get the following output:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "message": "Hello, world"
}
```

### Using query vars

> To customize the behavior of your controller, you will want to make use of the global `$json_api->query` object. Add the following method to your controller:

```
public function hello_person()
{
    global $json_api;
    $name = $json_api->query->name;
    return array(
        "message" => "Hello, $name."
    );
}
```

> Now append the name query var to the method call:

```
http://www.example.org/api/hello/hello_world/?dev=1&name=Alice
```

> ...or...

```
http://www.example.org/?json=hello.hello_world&dev=1&name=Alice.
```

> The result will be:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "message": "Hello, Alice"
}
```

> To make your controller visible from an external plugin or theme directory you will need to use two filters: `json_api_controllers` and `json_api_[controller]_controller_path`. Just create a custom plugin that holds your controller and add the following code:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#109019) Custom Hello JSON API Controller */

function add_hello_controller( $controllers )
{
    $controllers[] = 'hello';
    return $controllers;
}
add_filter( 'json_api_controllers', 'add_hello_controller' );

function set_hello_controller_path()
{
    return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."helloController.php";
}
add_filter( 'json_api_hello_controller_path', 'set_hello_controller_path' );

// >> Controller goes here <<

// A more organized file structure might work as well, but it's ok
// to stuff everything in a single file if used as mu-plugin.
```

You can use any sort of WP public API functions in your Controller. Still JSON API has a middle ware layer as well. Example:

```
global $json_api;
$posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts( array(
    'meta_key'   => $json_api->query->key,
    'meta_value' => $json_api->query->value
```

) );

Comment: A small hint about the version of the WP API should be helpful. The v2 is currently in Beta status and the v1 is legacy. I think is helpful for readers in the future. Your hooks from the v2, but is this solid in the WP universe ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [JSON API User](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/) plugin.  It advertises that it can register a new user for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use WP API v2, it has Users Controller implemented. If u are using V1, there is plugin someone mentioned above.